# Can I still add Facebook friend group as testers on Facebook app?

Tags: facebook, facebook-apps

Before the Facebook Developer website changed, I could add a friend group as testers for an app - making it easy to add more people as testers to multiple games, because I could just add them to the friend group.

I still have the friend group set as testers for my Facebook apps, however I'm trying to add a new friend group, but the new Facebook Developer website isn't letting me do it anymore.

Is there still a way to do it?